# LibreOffice 6.03 failed to start in Ubuntu 1804

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, libreoffice, gtk, compatibility

I installed LibreOffice 6.03 in Ubuntu 18.04 i386. When I click it's menu entry it's splash window pops up but not long after that it disappears. When I i fire it from the command line in a shell window it does the same, but the shell window shows these messages:

```
(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.560: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:27:35: Junk at end of value for background-color

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.560: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:40:48: Junk at end of value for background-color

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.560: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:48:46: Junk at end of value for background-color

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:59:58: Junk at end of value for background-color

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:66:28: The :prelight pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :hover instead.

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:70:46: Junk at end of value for background-color

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:77:35: The :prelight pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :hover instead.

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:81:58: Junk at end of value for background-color

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:123:31: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:124:24: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:156:27: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.561: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:157:29: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.562: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:177:34: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.

(soffice:11972): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:12:48.562: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:199:34: The :inconsistent pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :indeterminate instead.
```

---

How can it be fixed?

Comment: How did you install Libreoffice? The problem should not be there with the supported version in the software center, or with a snap version.

Comment: I installed it from the ubuntu 18.04 repository. for i386. I decided to uninstall and purge that version and installed version 6.2.8.2-2 downloaded from "The Document Foundation". Problem is now solved.